# ArcPy and filename.endswith not finding "l" (lower case L)

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase

I have several feature classes in a geodatabase that are named well001_well001s, well001_well001b, and well001_well001l. There are 765 individual features or 255*3.
This code selects all the names that end with "s" and mergers them into a single feature class.
It works with search = "s" and search = "b" but does not select anything when using search = "l"
(lower case L).
I've confirmed these FC's filenames end in l,
I've also tried adding .strip() to see if it removes and end of line character. But it didn't work. The code runs but nothing is selected. I also tried search = "*l"

The code walks and selects all the feature classes that end in the letter and mergers them into a single feature class. Does Python have a difficulty with the "l" character?

```
import arcpy
import os
workspace2 = r"D:\x.gdb"
search = "l"
outdir = r"D:\Tx_Spatial_Result.gdb"
fc = []
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace2, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Point")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(search):
            fc.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            print("selected")
            print(filename)
    print('done with walk')
    if fc:
        output = os.path.join(outdir, "TXlateral"+"_merge")
        arcpy.Merge_management(fc, output)
```

Comment: What this character is supposed to be ? an uppercase i, a lowercase L, a pipe symbol ? Did you try to copy/paste from one of your filename ? maybe you are in a similar situation as this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463159/qgis-sql-syntax-for-geopackage-layer-in-virtual-layer/463257#463257 (look for the accepted answer...)

Comment: J.R, i think this points out the issue as well. it's a lower case "L" or "l" but it looks like the "|" next to "\". I'm just reaching out to see if anyone has had a similar issue.

Comment: When in doubt, add a `print` statement to be sure you know the contents of variables above the `if` which is trying to restrict them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about "l" at all, it's an error in the Walk line of code. I overlooked this and realized i had it set to tpye = "point" and the feature classes that ended in "l" were Polylines. So Setting it to Type = "polyline" fixed it. Make sure to check code step by step! I was stuck on the search function when the error was in the walk proccess.

Comment: Kindly accept this as answer.

Comment: i will tomorrow, I can't accept for another day

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
if filename.lower().endswith(search):
```

Comment: Paashu, Thank you for this as well. I need to remove the type completely and test the code again.